# Interpret ORB matches in opencv Python

Tags: opencv, orb

I need to evaluate the results after using ORB and BFMatcher in OpenCV, such that I interpret the matches after comparing img1 to img3, and img2 to img3. I understand that ORB matches contain a list of hamming distances, but I want to convert this vector into a scalar value of similarity.

I thought of two scenarios:
1) using the length of matches, the higher indicates the great similarity. But how we deal if the length of matches1 = length matches2?. In this case, we can 2)add all distances, and the minimum is preferable.

Can we combine all cases into one metric?

Here is the minimum of my work:

```
orb = cv2.ORB()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
return len(matches)
```

Thanks

Comment: [DMatch](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/de0/classcv_1_1DMatch.html) is the type of matches returned by `bf.match`. So you can threshold the distances, basically you want the distances to be as low as possible but you need at least 4 Keypoints to define a homography. You can threshold them to get a set of **good matches** from the set of all matches. If you look at the DMatch class, you can find `queryIdx` and `trainIdx` which corresponds to Keypoint idx in the two images, so you can basically filter the Keypoints like that.

Comment: Thanks Rick. If I compute the homography to  match(img1-img3) 
 and homography to match(img2-img3). How quantitively can I compare the best match for img3?.

Comment: I don't get what you mean and why you would want to do that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well. I use to compare multiple images to the same image each time.  I run an optimization program, the cost function is taken from the output of comparing the two images. So I only need one value from image matching to represent the similarity. Within the optimization time, I test the current match and the previous one, and the output is used to tune a parameter.  So, my question is, how to transform the matches vector into a scalar? If you have any suggestion, please share! ... Thank you!

Comment: May be this isn't what you want or is absurd, but when I was doing something like this, I would store the corners of a rectangular, say a card on a plain background, which I would match with an image with only the card (no background). Then I would find the homography and check if these corners (in image coordinates) are actually what I stored. Basically analyzing the _goodness_ of the homography.

Comment: If you really want one value/similarity score, you can calculate the homography using RANSAC, and transform the image. Then you can use a suitbale similarity score.

Comment: Glad it could help! If you get a good answer to your question, add it as an answer, would be interesting to see :)

Comment: Hi Rick. How to accept it as an answer?

Comment: I could add it as an answer if you want to accept it :)